# Calculating premium splits for policies

Tags: python, performance, pandas, vectorization

Looking for a better approach to write below transformation using Python. Is it possible to avoid loop and still achieve the desired output?

It is too slow for 10 million rows.

```
#Below code calculate premium split for each policy

#import modules
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime 
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import date 
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore') 

#This function is to calculate financial year

def calculate_fy_dates(adj_date, year):
    
       #print(adj_date)
    if adj_date.month < 4:
        first_fy_start = pd.Timestamp(f"{year -1}-04-01")
        first_fy_end = pd.Timestamp(f"{year}-03-31")
    else:
        first_fy_start = pd.Timestamp(f"{year}-04-01")
        first_fy_end = pd.Timestamp(f"{year + 1}-03-31")
           
    second_fy_start = first_fy_start + relativedelta(years=1)
    second_fy_end = first_fy_end + relativedelta(years=1)
       
    return first_fy_start, first_fy_end,second_fy_start,second_fy_end


# This Function to calculate premium splits based on specified conditions
def calculate_premium_splits(row):
    premium_splits = []
    
    
    
    adj_date=row['ADJ_DATE']
        
    adjusted_adjustment_date=row['ADJ_DATE']
    annulized_prem=row['ANNULIZED']
    end_date=row['END_DATE1']
    today=pd.Timestamp.now()  
    today=pd.to_datetime(today)
    
    
    
    for year in range(today.year , today.year - 3, -1):
        
        first_fy_start, first_fy_end,second_fy_start,second_fy_end = calculate_fy_dates(row['ADJ_DATE'], year)
        dlta=year-adj_date.year
        adjust_dt=adjusted_adjustment_date+relativedelta(years=dlta)  
              
        # Calculate days in each fiscal year
        days_in_first_fy = (min(second_fy_start,today,end_date) - min(adjust_dt,end_date)).days 
        days_in_second_fy = (min(adjust_dt+relativedelta(years=1),end_date,today)-min(end_date,second_fy_start,today)).days
        
        premium_splits.append({
            'POLICY_REF': row['POLICY_REF'],
            "FIRST_FY_START":first_fy_start,
            "FIRST_FY_END":first_fy_end,
            "SECOND_FY_START":second_fy_start,
            "SECOND_FY_END":second_fy_end,
            'FIRST_FY': f"{first_fy_start.year}-{first_fy_end.year}",
            'SECOND_FY': f"{second_fy_start.year}-{second_fy_end.year}",
            'DAYS_IN_1ST_FY': days_in_first_fy,
            "FIRST_FY_PREM":round(row['ANNULIZED']*(days_in_first_fy/365),2),
            "COUNT_1":round(1*(days_in_first_fy/365),2),
            'DAYS_IN_2ND_FY': days_in_second_fy,
            "SECOND_FY_PREM":round(row['ANNULIZED']*(days_in_second_fy/365),2),
            "COUNT_2":round(1*(days_in_second_fy/365),2)
         })
      
    return pd.DataFrame(premium_splits)

#Function for Final output dataframe 
def get_outputdf(df):

    output_df = pd.concat(df.apply(calculate_premium_splits, axis=1).tolist(), ignore_index=True)
    print('output completed')
    output_df=df.merge(output_df,how='right')
    return output_df

    #output


# Generating sample Input data here 

data = {'POLICY_REF':['036652','033158','270054'],
        'START_DATE': ['15-07-2016','30-11-2016','25-3-2008'],#['25-3-2008','7-10-2006','30-11-2016'],
        'ADJ_DATE':['15-07-2016','30-11-2016','27-3-2008'],# ['27-3-2008','9-10-2006','30-11-2016'],
        'END_DATE1': ['12-01-2024','1-3-2024','25-3-2024'],#['25-3-2013','7-10-2009','28-11-2021'],
        'ANNULIZED': [25000,25000,10000]#[10000,10000,25000]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['START_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['START_DATE'], format='%d-%m-%Y')
df['ADJ_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ADJ_DATE'], format='%d-%m-%Y')
df['END_DATE1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['END_DATE1'], format='%d-%m-%Y')

df=get_outputdf(df)
```

Comment: Your indentation is all over the place, and at points it wasn't clear what was a comment and what was question markup. I've made some wild guesses. In the future, take care to use triple-backtick code fences and ensure PEP8-standard indentation in your code.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/288449/revisions) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://$SITEURL$/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

Remove your `warnings` ignore. The warnings are there for a reason.

Remove all of your unused `datetime` imports. Any half-decent IDE will show you which imports are unused.

Add type hints to your function signatures.

Don't format a date `f"{year -1}-04-01"` only to pass it directly to the `Timestamp` constructor; instead, pass the individual date fields as integers into the constructor.

`calculate_premium_splits` should not form a list. It should receive `row` as a `Series` already having a year field from a merge, and it should generate a single `Series` from the dictionary you  calculated. Don't write a `for` loop inside of `calculate_premium_splits`.

There are many calculations in this program that seem inaccurate. You shouldn't `round` until time of presentation, and having a hard-coded year length of 365 is a bad idea. Indeed, many of your fiscal years in this program have 366 days. I have left the calculations as-is in the first demonstration, with fixup guesses in the second demonstration (so the original regression test would not pass). You should have a finance professional carefully review these results before using them for any kind of real application.

Avoid baking year ranges like `2023-2024` into strings in the dataframe; instead, keep separate start and end years as integers in separate columns.

`ANNULIZED` is spelled `ANNUALIZED`.

Do not `concat(df.apply().tolist())` in `get_outputdf`. Instead, first perform a cross-merge on your year range, and then call the `apply` with no `concat`.

Move your sample data to a unit test.

Strongly consider replacing your inclusive-interval (March 31) endpoints with exclusive-interval (April 1) endpoints. [Half-open intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Definitions_and_terminology) simplify a lot of programming.

The above will get you halfway to sanity. More importantly, nearly all of the program needs to be re-written to be fully vectorised with no `apply()` at all. You'll need to figure this out field-by-field.

### Example (with apply)

This covers some of the above, but is not fully vectorised.

```py
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta


def calculate_fy_dates(
    adj_date: pd.Timestamp,
    year: int,
) -> tuple[
    pd.Timestamp,
    pd.Timestamp,
    pd.Timestamp,
    pd.Timestamp,
]:
    if adj_date.month < 4:
        year_delta = -1
    else:
        year_delta = 0

    first_fy_start = pd.Timestamp(year=year + year_delta, month=4, day=1)
    first_fy_end = pd.Timestamp(year=year + year_delta + 1, month=3, day=31)

    one_year = relativedelta(years=1)
    second_fy_start = first_fy_start + one_year
    second_fy_end = first_fy_end + one_year

    return first_fy_start, first_fy_end, second_fy_start, second_fy_end


def calculate_premium_splits(row: pd.Series, today: pd.Timestamp) -> pd.Series:
    """calculate premium splits based on specified conditions"""
    (
        first_fy_start, first_fy_end, second_fy_start, second_fy_end,
    ) = calculate_fy_dates(row['ADJ_DATE'], row.year)
    delta = row.year - row['ADJ_DATE'].year
    adjust_dt = row['ADJ_DATE'] + relativedelta(years=delta)

    # Calculate days in each fiscal year
    end_date = row['END_DATE1']
    days_in_first_fy = (
        min(second_fy_start, today, end_date) -
        min(adjust_dt, end_date)
    ).days
    days_in_second_fy = (
        min(adjust_dt + relativedelta(years=1), end_date, today) -
        min(end_date, second_fy_start, today)
    ).days

    premium_splits = {
        'FIRST_FY_START': first_fy_start,
        'FIRST_FY_END': first_fy_end,
        'SECOND_FY_START': second_fy_start,
        'SECOND_FY_END': second_fy_end,
        'FIRST_FY': f'{first_fy_start.year}-{first_fy_end.year}',
        'SECOND_FY': f'{second_fy_start.year}-{second_fy_end.year}',
        'DAYS_IN_1ST_FY': days_in_first_fy,
        'FIRST_FY_PREM': round(row['ANNUALIZED'] * (days_in_first_fy / 365), 2),
        'COUNT_1': round(days_in_first_fy / 365, 2),
        'DAYS_IN_2ND_FY': days_in_second_fy,
        'SECOND_FY_PREM': round(row['ANNUALIZED'] * (days_in_second_fy / 365), 2),
        'COUNT_2': round(days_in_second_fy / 365, 2),
    }

    return pd.Series(premium_splits)


def get_output_df(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Final output dataframe"""

    today = pd.Timestamp.now()
    today = pd.to_datetime(today)
    years = pd.RangeIndex(
        name='year', start=today.year, stop=today.year - 3, step=-1,
    ).to_series()
    merged = pd.merge(left=df, right=years, how='cross')
    applied = merged.apply(
        func=calculate_premium_splits,
        axis='columns', today=today,
    )
    output = pd.concat(objs=(merged, applied), axis='columns')
    return output.drop('year', axis='columns')


def test() -> None:
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'POLICY_REF': ['036652', '033158', '270054'],
        'START_DATE': ['15-07-2016', '30-11-2016', '25-3-2008'],
        'ADJ_DATE': ['15-07-2016', '30-11-2016', '27-3-2008'],
        'END_DATE1': ['12-01-2024', '1-3-2024', '25-3-2024'],
        'ANNUALIZED': [25000, 25000, 10000],
    })
    df['START_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['START_DATE'], format='%d-%m-%Y')
    df['ADJ_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ADJ_DATE'], format='%d-%m-%Y')
    df['END_DATE1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['END_DATE1'], format='%d-%m-%Y')

    df = get_output_df(df)
    expected = ''',POLICY_REF,START_DATE,ADJ_DATE,END_DATE1,ANNUALIZED,FIRST_FY_START,FIRST_FY_END,SECOND_FY_START,SECOND_FY_END,FIRST_FY,SECOND_FY,DAYS_IN_1ST_FY,FIRST_FY_PREM,COUNT_1,DAYS_IN_2ND_FY,SECOND_FY_PREM,COUNT_2
    0,036652,2016-07-15,2016-07-15,2024-01-12,25000,2023-04-01,2024-03-31,2024-04-01,2025-03-31,2023-2024,2024-2025,154,10547.95,0.42,0,0.0,0.0
    1,036652,2016-07-15,2016-07-15,2024-01-12,25000,2022-04-01,2023-03-31,2023-04-01,2024-03-31,2022-2023,2023-2024,260,17808.22,0.71,105,7191.78,0.29
    2,036652,2016-07-15,2016-07-15,2024-01-12,25000,2021-04-01,2022-03-31,2022-04-01,2023-03-31,2021-2022,2022-2023,260,17808.22,0.71,105,7191.78,0.29
    3,033158,2016-11-30,2016-11-30,2024-03-01,25000,2023-04-01,2024-03-31,2024-04-01,2025-03-31,2023-2024,2024-2025,16,1095.89,0.04,0,0.0,0.0
    4,033158,2016-11-30,2016-11-30,2024-03-01,25000,2022-04-01,2023-03-31,2023-04-01,2024-03-31,2022-2023,2023-2024,122,8356.16,0.33,243,16643.84,0.67
    5,033158,2016-11-30,2016-11-30,2024-03-01,25000,2021-04-01,2022-03-31,2022-04-01,2023-03-31,2021-2022,2022-2023,122,8356.16,0.33,243,16643.84,0.67
    6,270054,2008-03-25,2008-03-27,2024-03-25,10000,2022-04-01,2023-03-31,2023-04-01,2024-03-31,2022-2023,2023-2024,5,136.99,0.01,259,7095.89,0.71
    7,270054,2008-03-25,2008-03-27,2024-03-25,10000,2021-04-01,2022-03-31,2022-04-01,2023-03-31,2021-2022,2022-2023,5,136.99,0.01,360,9863.01,0.99
    8,270054,2008-03-25,2008-03-27,2024-03-25,10000,2020-04-01,2021-03-31,2021-04-01,2022-03-31,2020-2021,2021-2022,5,136.99,0.01,360,9863.01,0.99
    '''
    with StringIO(expected) as f:
        expected_df = pd.read_csv(
            f,
            index_col=0,
            dtype={'POLICY_REF': str},
        )
    assert (expected_df == df).all().all()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

### Example (full vectorisation)

This is basically fully vectorised. You'll need to carefully scrutinise it for accuracy.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

ONE_YEAR = pd.DateOffset(years=1)
ONE_DAY = pd.Timedelta(value=1, unit='D')


def fill_range(
    df: pd.DataFrame,
    base_name: str,
) -> None:
    """
    Fill out the end, string descriptions and day counts.
    Use half-open intervals for _END!
    """

    df[base_name + '_END'] = df[base_name + '_START'] + ONE_YEAR
    # + pd.DateOffset(
    #     years=1, month=3, day=31,
    # )  # not a half-open interval

    df[base_name] = (
        df[base_name + '_START'].dt.year.astype(str) + '-' +
        df[base_name + '_END'].dt.year.astype(str)
    )


def get_output_df(df: pd.DataFrame, today: pd.Timestamp) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Final output dataframe"""

    year_index = pd.date_range(
        name='FIRST_FY_START',
        start=today,
        end=today + pd.DateOffset(years=-2),
        freq='-1Y',
    ).to_series()
    first_fy_fields = pd.DataFrame({
        'year': year_index.dt.year, 'month': 4, 'day': 1,
    })
    first_fy_start = pd.to_datetime(first_fy_fields)
    first_fy_start.name = year_index.name

    df = pd.merge(left=df, right=first_fy_start, how='cross')
    broadcast_years = df['FIRST_FY_START'].copy()
    df.loc[
        df['ADJ_DATE'].dt.month < 4,
        'FIRST_FY_START',
    ] -= ONE_YEAR
    df['SECOND_FY_START'] = df['FIRST_FY_START'] + ONE_YEAR

    fill_range(df, base_name='FIRST_FY')
    fill_range(df, base_name='SECOND_FY')

    adj_date_fields = pd.DataFrame({
        'year': broadcast_years.dt.year,
        'month': df['ADJ_DATE'].dt.month,
        'day': df['ADJ_DATE'].dt.day,
    })
    adjust_dt = pd.to_datetime(adj_date_fields)

    second_start_clipped = df[[
        'SECOND_FY_START', 'END_DATE1',
    ]].min(axis=1).clip(upper=today)

    df['DAYS_IN_1ST_FY'] = (
        second_start_clipped - np.minimum(
            df['END_DATE1'], adjust_dt,
        )
    ) / ONE_DAY

    df['DAYS_IN_2ND_FY'] = (
        np.minimum(
            df['END_DATE1'], adjust_dt + ONE_YEAR,
        ).clip(upper=today) - second_start_clipped
    ) / ONE_DAY

    # Don't hard-code 365
    year_days = (
        df[['FIRST_FY_END', 'SECOND_FY_END']].values -
        df[['FIRST_FY_START', 'SECOND_FY_START']].values
    ) / ONE_DAY

    df[[
        'FIRST_FY_PREM', 'SECOND_FY_PREM',
    ]] = df['ANNUALIZED'].values[:, np.newaxis] * df[[
        'DAYS_IN_1ST_FY', 'DAYS_IN_2ND_FY',
    ]].values / year_days

    df[['COUNT_1', 'COUNT_2']] = df[[
        'DAYS_IN_1ST_FY', 'DAYS_IN_2ND_FY',
    ]] / year_days

    return df


def test() -> None:
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'POLICY_REF': ['036652', '033158', '270054'],
        'START_DATE': ['2016-07-15', '2016-11-30', '2008-03-25'],
        'ADJ_DATE': ['2016-07-15', '2016-11-30', '2008-03-27'],
        'END_DATE1': ['2024-01-12', '2024-03-01', '2024-03-25'],
        'ANNUALIZED': [25000, 25000, 10000],
    })
    df['START_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['START_DATE'])
    df['ADJ_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ADJ_DATE'])
    df['END_DATE1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['END_DATE1'])

    df = get_output_df(df, today=pd.Timestamp('2023-12-16'))

    pd.options.display.max_columns = 20
    pd.options.display.width = 200
    print(df)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```